# Stopping multiline textInput component to scroll inside ScrollView

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview, react-native-textinput

I am working on `React Native` in which I want to stop multiline textinput component's scroll inside ScrollView. How we can achieve it? **Android Specially!**

Comment: i didn't understand what do you mean, clarify and try to add your code for a better vision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use textinput option `scrollEnabled`

but this option only use `ios`, not work `android`

```js
scrollEnabled={false}
```

So I recommend that you set the height and specify the maxLength of letters to prevent scrolling from being seen.

- example

```js
style={{height : 0000}}
maxLength={0000}
```

Comment: I already know that. But I am voting up because you tried to help.

Comment: @MuhammadRafehAtique does this solution not work or what exactly is wrong?

Comment: @DavidScholz I tried this and it works for IOS specially but there is problem related to android! I want react native to stop scroll. Now what I am doing is giving height related to content size but for different fonts it sometime comes in scrolling inside scrollView

Comment: @hongdeveloper I'm accepting it as there are no another answers coming.